# edit the output of jdoc:include type=head via renderer/head.php alter

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, head

I would like to order nicely the head section of a joomla site. After search of the forums I have come across this one http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=642&t=671526&p=3283757#p3283757

There a nice suggestion is to copy the /renderer/head.php file into the template folder and alter it to current needs.

They suggest

> Blockquote
>   The render function in head.php not uses the $name var, so it`s fine to use to separate the js and metatags with css files and use the jdoc statement like this:

```
jdoc:include type="head" name="head"  <-- will include all exept js (into
                                          the head section)
jdoc:include type="head" name="foot" <-- for the js (before body tag closes)
```

> Blockquote

But I simply have no idea how to implement this.

HAve someone experience with editing head.php in Joomla? I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I investigated a little bit about it and it seems a little bit hacky to do it.

This solution is currently working on Joomla 3.*.

First of all you have to modify `/librabies/joomla/document/document.php`.
Once you are in there update the function loadRenderer() from this:

```php
public function loadRenderer($type)
{
    $class = 'JDocumentRenderer' . $type;   

    if (!class_exists($class))
    {
        $path = __DIR__ . '/' . $this->_type . '/renderer/' . $type . '.php';

        if (file_exists($path))
        {
            require_once $path;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new RuntimeException('Unable to load renderer class', 500);
        }
    }

    if (!class_exists($class))
    {
        return null;
    }

    $instance = new $class($this);

    return $instance;
}
```

To this :

```php
public function loadRenderer($type)
{
    $class = 'JDocumentRenderer' . $type;   

    if (!class_exists($class))
    {
        $path = __DIR__ . '/' . $this->_type . '/renderer/' . $type . '.php';

        $app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
        $path_custom = JPATH_THEMES . '/' . $app->getTemplate() .'/html/renderer/' . $type . '.php';

        if (file_exists($path_custom))
        {
            require_once $path_custom;
        }
        elseif (file_exists($path))
        {
            require_once $path;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new RuntimeException('Unable to load renderer class', 500);
        }
    }

    if (!class_exists($class))
    {
        return null;
    }

    $instance = new $class($this);

    return $instance;
}
```

Actually the new code is looking for a render file in your template directory.

Now you are allow to copy `libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php` to `templates/TEMPLATE_NAME/html/renderer/head.php` and modify it.

If you want to use those :

```
<jdoc:include type="head" name="head" />
<jdoc:include type="head" name="foot" />
```

Update `templates/TEMPLATE_NAME/html/renderer/head.php` to  this version [here](http://pastebin.com/fPq8wSBc).

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! I was busy today with checking the scripts. First: I managed to load the new templates/template_name/renderer/head.php with adding the require_once __DIR__ .'/renderer/head.php'; after define or die declaration. So I don't have to hack the code of document.php. So the original files stay complete, without changes. The head part with css links and metatags loads perfect.  But the part with scripts won't load. I use the <jdoc:include type="head" name="footer" /> just before closing the </head>.

Comment: He, my bad, I've just noticed a type mistake. Footer was not spelled right. Oooh... Thank you very much for your awesome code!!! Really really appreciate your help! I think many people would find it very useful too since this problem bothering a lot of people around, but your solution is the only one clear and working so far.

Comment: Update: since the update of joomla to 3.5 the class _JDocumentRendererHead_ is deprecated. So in order to let the things work you could use _class JDocumentRendererHtmlHead_ (arond the line 17), instead of _class JDocumentRendererHead_

Comment: Now it lies in `libraries\src\Document\Renderer\Html` A file called `HeadRenderer.php`

Answer (score 2):

Another option (for joomla 2.5/3.0 and with slightly adjustments joomla 3.5.x) as mention [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/tutorials/joomla/36-customize-the-jdoc-include-type-head-part.html) is the following:

1.) grap the "/libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php" from a Joomla 3.0 installation ZIP file

2.) rename that to "head_renderer.php" and put that into your template folder

3.) in your template index.php add:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'head_renderer.php';
```

4.) If you are still using Joomla 3.0 you are fine, if you are using Joomla 3.5 edit head_renderer.php and change JDocumentRendererHead to JDocumentRendererHtmlHead.

5.) Adjust the head_renderer.php so that it fits your requirements